# LDAP works with PHP CLI but not through apache

Tags: php, windows, ldap

I'm trying to authenticate over LDAP against a Windows 2008 Server from a Fedora box.

The following code works from the command line (prints "Success"):

```
if($ldap = ldap_connect('10.0.0.101'))
{
  ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
  $bind = ldap_bind($ldap,'administrator@domain.tld','XXXXXXX');
  print ldap_error($ldap);
}
```

...pulling the same file via Apache/mod_php prints "Can't contact LDAP server"

I've seen a lot of reports of issues like this, but no useful information on how to resolve it.

Comment: I had the same problem yesterday on Ubuntu 18.04 with the stock Apache, PHP 7.2, LDAP  and libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit, but only with LDAPS not LDAP, and it is gone now, and I can't tell you what made it go away :-(

Answer (score 12):

I just fought this exact problem for a long time on centos6.  The php.ini difference seem like a good place to check, but it didn't give me the answer.  It turns out this was related to SELinux.

```
$ getsebool -a | grep httpd
allow_httpd_anon_write --> off
allow_httpd_mod_auth_ntlm_winbind --> off
allow_httpd_mod_auth_pam --> off
allow_httpd_sys_script_anon_write --> off
httpd_builtin_scripting --> on
httpd_can_check_spam --> off
httpd_can_network_connect --> off
httpd_can_network_connect_cobbler --> off
httpd_can_network_connect_db --> on
httpd_can_network_memcache --> on
httpd_can_network_relay --> off
httpd_can_sendmail --> off
httpd_dbus_avahi --> on
httpd_enable_cgi --> on
httpd_enable_ftp_server --> off
httpd_enable_homedirs --> off
httpd_execmem --> off
httpd_manage_ipa --> off
httpd_read_user_content --> off
httpd_run_stickshift --> off
httpd_setrlimit --> off
httpd_ssi_exec --> off
httpd_tmp_exec --> off
httpd_tty_comm --> on
httpd_unified --> on
httpd_use_cifs --> off
httpd_use_gpg --> off
httpd_use_nfs --> off
httpd_use_openstack --> off
httpd_verify_dns --> off
```

You'll note, that in my case, httpd_can_network_connect was set to off.  This is a boolean in SELinux and can be adjusted with the following command.

```
$ setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on
```

You can read more about this at http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/SelinuxBooleans which explicitly uses the case of apache and ldap as an example.  Hope it helps!

Comment: A thousand thanks for this answer.  Been struggling with this for a day now and running across multitudes of dead ends.   Thanks again.

Comment: In 2024 on RHEL7, the bool is called httpd_can_connect_ldap. Other than that, it's the same analysis and the same fix. Thanks, @cyberswat.

Answer (score 1):

You might be having this problem because Apache has one `php.ini` file and `CLI` might have another, and the Apache version might not have `LDAP` extension enabled.

Try checking which `php.ini` is loading with [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) in both of your environments:

```
<?php print phpinfo(); ?>
```

You should see the path of `php.ini` and additional useful information:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
```

An alternative method to see the configuration loaded on the `CLI` is by calling `php` with `-i` parameter:

```
$ php -i | grep 'php.ini'
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

Comment: That was among the first things I checked.  Unfortunately, they're loading the same ini.  This is Fedora 16, btw.