# ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server

Tags: php, symfony, ldap

I'm trying to connect to an LDAP server in a Symfony application. And I'm having some difficulties.

When locally tested, everything worked fine. I could easily connect and bind to the LDAP server through following code:

```
    $un = $user->getUsername();
    if (!$connect = ldap_connect("10.XX.XX.X", 389)) {
        $auth = false;
    } else {
        if($password !== null){
            if (!$res = ldap_bind($connect, $un, $password)) {
                $auth = false;
            } else {
                $auth = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

but when on server, it gives me:

```
Warning: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server in LdapProvider.php on line 71
```

I'm guessing this is due to wrong configuration server-side. I'm fairly new to LDAP though, so is there anyone who can help me out here?

Comment: Is your file LdapProvider.php? And what's on line 71? You try to connect to same ldap server locally and on server?

Comment: Have you tried hardcoding the username and password and give a shot ?

Comment: I have tried hard coding, yes, but no results. And it throws the error on ldap_bind() - that's what's on line 71. 

And no, I've developed the project locally and now I want to deploy it.

Comment: check if you are authorized to connect to your ldap server from your local.

Comment: How do I do that, paistra?

Comment: that'll be because it's an OR operator, but indeed, I should correct that

Comment: your code works well with my ldap connection, may be it is a server issue

Comment: @HelenaStandaert ask your sysadmin if you can access to ldap from server. But where's your ldap? On your local machine? On other server? To test if you can access to ldap server try simple `telnet yourldapserver 389 `

Comment: The LDAP is on another server, I guess.. and what do you mean with the telnet? is that a command for windows cmd??

Comment: Download LDAP admin tool[http://www.ldapadmin.org/download/ldapadmin.html] then set your LDAP settings and try to connect; that will help you to check LDAP connection without using any command

Comment: I have downloaded ldapadmin and logged into the server without any problems.. I really can't see why I get this error...

Answer (score 0):

Same problem as OP - ldap would work with the binary php, but not through Apache.   Figured there was an issue with the CA, but that turned out not to be the case.

SELinux is running Enforced.   When I temporarily disabled SELinux, the ldap test script worked fine in a browser.  That eventually led me to this [helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15117996/721073) and this [CentOS Wiki on SELinux](https://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/SelinuxBooleans).  Here we learn:

> SELinux doesn't allow your httpd daemon to talk to the LDAP
>   server on the same machine.

So it turns out SELinux has a multitude of fine-grained switches to allow specific activity from different processes.  In my case, SELinux was configured out of the box to disallow LDAP connectivity (even though ldaps is enabled in firewalld).

You can check SELinux configuration of httpd using:

```
getsebool -a | grep httpd
```

which returns:

```
[acoder@myboxen]# getsebool -a | grep httpd
httpd_anon_write --> off
httpd_builtin_scripting --> on
httpd_can_check_spam --> off
httpd_can_connect_ftp --> off
httpd_can_connect_ldap --> off
httpd_can_connect_mythtv --> off
httpd_can_connect_zabbix --> off
httpd_can_network_connect --> off
```

To enable SELinux network connectivity through httpd:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on
```

No need to restart Apache.  My ldap script worked fine from that moment on.

As above, be sure to set SELinux back to `Enforcing` with `setenforce 1` if you temporarily disabled it to test.

Hope this is helpful to others.